# Is it possible to clear only the in memory cache in a NSURLCache?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

[This post](http://twobitlabs.com/2012/01/ios-ipad-iphone-nsurlcache-uiwebview-memory-utilization/) recommends doing this:

```
- (void)applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
}
```

However, that will take both the on disk and the in memory cache.  Does something like this work to just evict the in memory cache?

```
NSURLCache *cache = [NSURLCache sharedURLCache];
NSUInteger currentMemoryCapacity = cache.memoryCapacity;

// Not sure if this works? Docs seem to say it will trigger an evict.
// https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSURLCache_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLCache/setMemoryCapacity:
cache.memoryCapacity = 0; 
cache.memoryCapacity = currentMemoryCapacity;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that code should evict the memory cache.  (And does on iOS 7.1.1, in my brief test.)

If you're looking for finer control over the cache, check out [Peter Steinberger's fork of `SDURLCache`](https://github.com/steipete/SDURLCache) which has (for example) a `-removeAllCachedResponsesInMemory` method.

Answer (score 0):

This no longer appears to work (tested on the iOS 9.2 simulator)

Although the cache's reported memoryCapacity changes, the actual memoryUsage reported doesn't :-(